# Binomial coefficients with real number

Tags: binomial-coefficients, real-numbers

I am studying the book *[Loop, knots, gauge theories and quantum gravity](https://books.google.it/books?id=S5IYVY0PrRQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=it&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)* by Gambini and Pullin. In chapter 2 eqn 2.24 pag 35, when dealing with the extended group of loops, the authors use the binomial coefficients with real numbers. How are binomial coefficients extended to real numbers?

Comment: In the form $\binom x k$ where $x$ is real?  If so, it's just a polynomial in $x$, the obvious extension of the usual.

Comment: @kimchilover yes in that form.

Comment: and complex using the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For real $x$, or complex $x$, the formula $$\binom x k = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac {x-i} {k-i}$$ extends the usual definition of binomial coefficients.  This is what's used in the ["Generalized binomial theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem).

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the gamma function
$$\binom x k =\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(k+1)\,\,\Gamma(x-k+1)}$$

Source: equation (2) in following [link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html)